# GatsyJS, GraphQL - Issue mapping through array.

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, gatsby

I'm building a decoupled drupal site with GatsbyJS. I'm trying to display the title of nodePersonalInformation. Here is the query in the GatsbyJS graphQL playground :

```
{
  allUserUser(filter: {name: {eq: "bobdole"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        relationships {
          nodePersonalInformation {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query Result :

```
{
  "data": {
    "allUserUser": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "name": "bobdole",
            "relationships": {
              "nodePersonalInformation": [
                {
                  "title": "bobdole"
                },
                {
                  "title": "bobdole"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm successfully displaying "name" using these variables :

```
const data = this.props.data.allUserUser.edges
const personalInfo = data.map(pI => <span>{pI.node.name}</span>)
```

However, because "nodePersonalInformation" is an array, I can't work out how to display the "title". I've tried a .map inside a .map with no luck. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the two title properties contained in `nodePersonalInformation` and after, get first element of this array.

To do this, first of all, you have to get `nodePersonalInformation`.
Try with this

```
const titles = data.map(edge => edge.node.relationships.nodePersonalInformation.map(title => title)[0]);
```

`[0]` at the end of the line allows you to get only the first result of first `map`. If you don't do this, you get an array of arrays.

After, you can get the title you want with this line :
    `const uniqueTitle = title[0]`

If you have always one edge, you can also force to get first edges item :
`const data = this.props.data.edges[0]`. In this way, you don't need `[0]` when you get title array.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and received - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodePersonalInformation' of null" in the console.

Comment: Because `allUserUser` level is missing. Try `data.allUserUser.edges.map()`

Comment: Thanks, please can you update the stackblitz so the title in NodePersonalInformation is displayed in a div.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @ghunteur.

Comment: You can approve the answer now